Mapperly - must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers
I have a .net framework 4.6.1 Application, and im using few c# libraries which are targeting .net standard 2.0, Im using Mapperly to map my domain to External DTOS.
I am facing an issue when im trying to run my code in a docker container(windows), which im not able to get any build errors in my local Visual studio.
My Sample Implementation of this is
[Mapper]
public partial class CustomerMapper
{
public partial CustomerItem MapBLLRequestToDomain(Dealer request);
public partial Dealer MapDomainRequestToBLL(CustomerItem request);
public partial List MapBLLRequestToDomain(List request);
public partial List MapDomainRequestToBLL(List request);

}

this mapper is implemented in one library and is used in multiple libraries in the application, now when i build this i get the error -
2024-07-30T20:01:16.7795588Z   D:\a\1\s\myproject\test\test\Mappers\CustomerMapper.cs(10,37): error CS8795: Partial method 'CustomerMapper.MapBLLRequestToDomain(Dealer)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers. [D:\a\1\s\myproject\test\test.csproj] 2024-07-30T20:01:16.7796447Z   D:\a\1\s\myproject\test\test\Mappers\CustomerMapper.cs(12,43): error CS8795: Partial method 'CustomerMapper.MapBLLRequestToDomain(List)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers. [D:\a\1\s\myproject\test\test.csproj] 2024-07-30T20:01:16.7797320Z   DD:\a\1\s\myproject\test\test\Mappers\CustomerMapper.cs(11,62): error CS8795: Partial method 'CustomerMapper.MapDomainRequestToBLL(CustomerItem)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers. [D:\a\1\s\myproject\test\test.csproj] 2024-07-30T20:01:16.7798541Z   D:\a\1\s\myproject\test\test\Mappers\CustomerMapper.cs(13,68): error CS8795: Partial method 'CustomerMapper.MapDomainRequestToBLL(List)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers. [D:\a\1\s\myproject\test\test.csproj
